# How can I minimize keystrokes while inserting similar lines in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets, vim-macros

Sometimes I need to insert some similar lines in a file which differ only in a sequence number. For example,

```
print "func 1";
print "func 2";
print "func 3";
print "func 4";
print "func 5";
```

Using **vim**, I end up copy pasting the first line using [yypppp] and then changing the last four lines. This is really slow if you have more lines to insert.

**Is there a faster way to do this in vim?**

---

An example of this is:

> Initial state

```
boot();
format();
parse();
compare();
results();
clean();
```

> Final state

```
print "func 1";
format();
print "func 2";
parse();
print "func 3";
compare();
print "func 4";
results();
print "func 5";
clean();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Record a macro. Here is the workflow for your particular example:

Copy-paste the first line. Then,

```
qa       : Start recording macro to register a
yy       : Yank current line
p        : Paste current line in line below
/\d      : Search for start of number (you can skip this command, the next command automagically moves the cursor to the number)
C-A      : Control-A increments the number
q        : Stop recording macro
3@a      : Replay macro 3 times
```

You can replace 3 with any number to keep generating new `print` lines with incremented numbers.

For your second example, you can just add

```
j        : Moves one line down
```

after the `yy` command, to get alternating lines of commands and `print`'s.

Comment: You don't actually need to do `/[0-9]\+`, VIM Automagically moves the cursor to the number

Comment: You can replace `/[0-9]\+` with a much better `/\d` (you do not need to get the whole number into a match, you need only to place cursor on a number, so `\+` is an overkill here. `\d` is a shortcut to `[0-9]`. It is faster, but this does not matter here. It also minimizes number of keys that should be pressed.).

Answer (score 1):

You have plugins that do it. For example, [visincr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=670). Visually select your column of numbers, and run `:I`.

Another way to do it is to record a macro. run `qx` to start recording macro to register *x*, `yiw` to yank word under the cursor, `j` to go one line down, `viwp` to paste it, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to increment the new number, `q` to stop recording, and then `@x` to replay contents of register *x*.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you could use a macro. There's a good write-up of how to do sequence numbers in [this post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/vi-and-vim-macro-tutorial-how-to-record-and-play/).

You need to change the example in the post to write out the entire line first and then record a macro that copies the line and updates the counter.